# Method reference in Java unil BiFunction

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I have question about passing method reference as argument in java (util) functions.

I have two functions

```
Function<Value, Output> f1 = (val) -> {
    Output o = new Output();
    o.setAAA(val);
    return o;
};

Function<Value, Output> f2 = (val) -> {
    Output o = new Output();
    o.setBBB(val);
    return o;
};
```

I want to merge them into one function which should looked like

```
BiFunction<MethodRefrence, Value, Output> f3 = (ref, val) -> {
    Output o = new Output();
    Output."use method based on method reference"(val);
    return o;
};
```

I want to use this function like

```
f3.apply(Output::AAA, number);
```

Is it possible ? I can't figure out correct syntax, how to make such a function.

Comment: It sounds like you should have `BiConsumer<Value, Output>` values for your first two... then `f3` can create the `Output` and call `f1` and `f2` with the *same* `Output` and `Value`. After all, you don't want to call `new Output()` three times.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: maybe he wants a new `Output` each time. Btw, it must be `BiConsumer<Output, Value>` rather than `BiConsumer<Value, Output>` if you want to support method references like `Output::AAA` as the method receiver comes first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you want a function like

```
BiFunction<BiConsumer<Output,Value>, Value, Output> f = (func, val) -> {
    Output o = new Output();
    func.accept(o, val);
    return o;
};
```

which you can invoke like

```
f.apply(Output::setAAA, val);
f.apply(Output::setBBB, val);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean with "method reference", but I think you want something like this:

```
BiFunction<Integer, Value, Output> f3 = (ref, val> -> {
    switch(ref) {
        case 1: return f1.apply(value);
        case 2: return f2.apply(value);
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid index");
    }
}
```

You can replace the Integer with anything you'd like, as long as you also change the switch-statement, maybe use an if/else.

Comment: [Enhancements in Java SE 8 ‣ Method References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: Oh, this thing. I don't see use of this BiFunction then, since you would basically just have to give it a Function that gets executed by it.